# English Equivalent of "修煉"?

Tags: translation

For example

> 修煉體係

What would an English translation for that be? Google says "Taoism", but that doesn't sound right, although it may be very slightly correct.

I could only think of "Qi practicing" or "Spirit practicing", but would there be any better ones?

Also, would

> 修真

Be the same?

Comment: Do you have an example context in which these words appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**KEY** has two definitions for 修炼:

> practice asceticism
>
> practice self-cultivation (esp. of a Taoist)

*self-cultivation* has a nice ring to it.

**修真** on the other hand means:

> {Taoism} cultivate true virtue

修炼 has quite a wide range of meanings one of which is the same as 修真: 修行.

修真 only really has one meaning.

Although it might be interchangeable in some cases, the context is really important here.